I have requirement where i need create button visible to only specific country in LWC
I have requirement where i need create button visible to only spain country in LWC,so i have used below code.but if i keep if:true={isspain} button is not visible and if it is false then button is showing for all the countries.
I have fix this as it has to be visible only to spain.
so i have used below code.
<template>
    <template if:false={hideComponent}>
        <div class="d-flex">
            <div class="ml-auto">
                <template if:true={isspain}>
                    <lightning-button variant="brand" label={labels.Find_a_Lab} title={labels.Find_a_Lab} 
                  onclick={Find_a_Lab} icon-name="utility:forward" > </lightning-button>
                </template>

import { LightningElement,api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import { CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';
import isGuest from "@salesforce/user/isGuest";
import getUserDetails from '@salesforce/apex/b2BOrderManagementController.getUserDetails';
export default class B2B_NavigationLink extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    isguest = isGuest; 
    isspain;
    getUserInfo() {
        getUserDetails({
            userId: this.userId
           }).then(results => {
                console.log('getUserDetails',JSON.stringify(results));
                this.userDetails=JSON.parse(results);
                console.log("this.userdetails"+ this.userDetails);
               if(this.userDetails[0].Country == 'Spain')
               {
               this.isspain = true;
               
               console.log("Country is"+ this.userDetails[0].Country);              
                }
                else{
                    this.isspain = false;
                }
                
        });
    }
    Find_a_Lab(){
        window.location = this.labels.Find_a_Lab_URL;
    }


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

i have to create a new button in LWC for which has to visible only to specific country(spain).based on user country i can say.i have added above code to existing code but it can see button  only  if i keep this condition if :false={isspain} .

Repeating what you've already added to the question is generally not helpful. Start by examining the console output of your LWC. Keep in mind that you need to have something that calls your getUserInfo() js function (which in turn imperatively calls your Apex method) for isspain to be anything other than undefined in your current Javascript. That could be placing the call inside of connectedCallback() but my LWC experience is limited.

Is there a function that calls getUserInfo? Please edit the question adding the whole JS Class or at least all the relevant parts.

Looking at the code, the method, this.getUserInfo, needs to be called in the connectedCallback which performs initialization tasks, such as fetch data, set up caches, or listen for events.
The modified code is:
// other code remains same
/** Adding connected callback* */

connectedCallback(){
    this.getUserInfo();
}
/***/
getUserInfo() {
        // same code
    }
  // other code remains same
}

Hope this resolves your issue.

Thankyou,I will add above code.
